# Position sticky SVG element contained inside div with overflow

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-redux

Is there a way to a way to use `position: sticky` inside SVG? Similar to how [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45222155/813689) example work.

To complicate the matter slightly, I am looking to use `position: sticky` inside an SVG element inside another `div` with `overflow:auto`. I have a created an example of what I am trying to achieve inside [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-static-content-while-scrolling-r85eb).

Edit 1:
Not sure whether this makes a difference, but for context in my own application I am using react & react-redux to include/exclude shapes to form a graph. The requirement is to keep some elements at the top of the view port when scrolling the same way Excel would if you would to freeze a header/row.

Edit 2: Updated the sandbox to include the answer's code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  `position` is a property that only applies to HTML elements. It is not valid inside an SVG.

You would need to use Javascript.  Add an onscroll event handler to watch the scroll and reposition the SVG element.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(evt) {

  document.getElementById("sticky-rect").setAttribute("y", screenYtoSVGUnits(window.scrollY) + 10);

});


// Converts a screen Y position to SVG units which have a viewBox transform
function screenYtoSVGUnits(val) {
  const svg = document.getElementById("mysvg");
  let pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = 0;
  pt.y = val;
  pt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getCTM().inverse());
  return pt.y;
}
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg" viewBox="0 0 100 500">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="500" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
  <rect id="sticky-rect" x="0" y="10" width="100" height="10" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: After posting the question I actually started work on exactly this kind of solution as an alternate solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is great. Do you think there's a way to apply to a <g> so when we scroll, we have multiple sticky rects?

Comment: @SixtyEight Yes you could do that.  Although the `<g>` element doesn't have `x` and `y` attributes.  SO you would need to use a `transform` attribute instead. For example `.setAttribute("transform", "translate(0," + screenYtoSVGUnits(window.scrollY) + ")"));`

Comment: It worked thanks a lot! Unfortunately is not performant enough since on my case, I wanna build a Gantt chart with panning both X and Y with both sticky axis. I'm using this for that but it flickers a lot. Can't find any suitable examples anywhere unfortunately. And my yAxis is categorical, I think scaleBand doesn't zoom.

Comment: @SixtyEight were you able to do anything